# Move hidden UICollectionViewCell seamlessly with a custom UICollectionViewLayout

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I implemented a custom mechanism to perform reordering using drag and drop in a `UICollectionView`, using a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`.

I have a very simple [`UICollectionView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview) with a custom [`UICollectionViewLayout`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewlayout).
My layout class **is not** a subclass of [`UICollectionViewFlowLayout`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewflowlayout).

Here is how it looks like:

[image: layout]

When I start lifting a cell to begin the drag, I update a `dropProposalIndexPath` property in my custom layout object so it knows which cell needs to be hidden.

My custom `UICollectionViewLayout` subclass returns a `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes` with the `alpha` property set to 0 for the cell which corresponds to `dropProposalIndexPath` like so:

```swift
if self.dropProposalIndexPath == indexPath {
    itemLayoutAttributes.alpha = 0
}
```

It makes the lifted cell hidden thus creating a "hole" in the `UICollectionView`.

When the user moves its finger, I update the `dropProposalIndexPath` property of my custom `UICollectionViewLayout` subclass and invalidate its layout, then move the cell that acts as a hole at the new indexPath:

```swift
// Inform layout of the indexPath of the dropProposal
self.reorderableLayout?.dropProposalIndexPath = dropProposalIndexPath
// Move the cell 
collectionView.moveItem(at: draggingIndexPath, to: dropProposalIndexPath)
```

Here is how it looks:

[image: video demonstrating cell blinking when moving]

Pretty bad huh?

I implemented the exact same logic in a demo project using a subclass of `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and the transition is seamless:

[image]

I guess I'm doing something wrong or forget to do something in my `UICollectionViewLayout` subclass.

I can post more code if needed.

---

Please note that using the built-in drag & drop mechanism (introduced with iOS 11) to perform the reordering is not an option, I want to use my custom implementation for various reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case someone encounters the same issue, the solution was to implement the following method in your `UICollectionViewLayout` subclass:

```swift
func initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItem(at: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes?
```

You then return a `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes` with the `alpha` property set to `0` in the `initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItem` function if the `itemIndexPath` parameter matches the indexPath of your dragging cell.